# How to write windowed aggregation in CSV format?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am developing a Spark Structured Streaming application that streams csv files and joins them with a static data. I have done some aggregation after join.

While writing the query result to HDFS in CSV format, I am getting the following error:

```
19/01/09 14:00:30 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 830ca987-b55a-4c03-aa13-f71bc57e47ad, runId = 87cdb029-0022-4f1c-b55e-c2443c9f058a] terminated with error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CSV data source does not support struct<start:timestamp,end:timestamp> data type.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVUtils$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$csv$CSVUtils$$verifyType$1(CSVUtils.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVUtils$$anonfun$verifySchema$1.apply(CSVUtils.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVUtils$$anonfun$verifySchema$1.apply(CSVUtils.scala:131)
```

What could be the root cause?

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
  .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
  .config("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation", "/user/sas/sparkCheckpoint")
  .getOrCreate

...

val df_agg_without_time = sqlResultjoin
  .withWatermark("event_time", "10 seconds")
  .groupBy(
    window($"event_time", "10 seconds", "5 seconds"),
    $"section",
    $"timestamp")
  .agg(sum($"total") as "total")

...

finalTable_repo
  .writeStream
  .outputMode("append")
  .partitionBy("xml_data_dt")
  .format("csv")
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("2 seconds"))
  .option("path", "hdfs://op/apps/hive/warehouse/area.db/finalTable_repo")
  .start
```

Comment: This [blog](https://www.pavanpkulkarni.com/blog/20-structured-streaming-file-to-file-processing/)  could probably help you. The blog talks about JSON vs CSV in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line where you do aggregation `.groupBy(window($"event_time", "10 seconds", "5 seconds"), $"section", $"timestamp")` creates the `struct<start:timestamp,end:timestamp>` data type that is not supported by the CSV data source.

Just `df_agg_without_time.printSchema` and you see the column.

A solution is simply to transform it to some other simpler type (possibly with `select` or `withColumn`) or just `select` it out (i.e. not include in the following dataframe).

---

The following is a sample batch (non-streaming) structured query that shows the schema that your streaming structured query uses (when you create `df_agg_without_time`).

```
val q = spark
  .range(4)
  .withColumn("t", current_timestamp)
  .groupBy(window($"t", "10 seconds"))
  .count
scala> q.printSchema
root
 |-- window: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- start: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- end: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = false)
```

For a sample streaming query, you could use the rate data source.

```
val q = spark
  .readStream
  .format("rate")
  .load
  .groupBy(window($"timestamp", "10 seconds"))
  .count
scala> q.printSchema
root
 |-- window: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- start: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |    |-- end: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = false)
```