# Empty CSV file is getting generated after processing spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

when i try to write some spark structured streaming data to csv, i see empty part files getting generated on hdfs location. I have tried to write same on console and the data getting generated to console.

```
   val spark =SparkSession.builder().appName("micro").
    enableHiveSupport().config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true").
    config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict").
    config("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation", "/user/sasidhr1/sparkCheckpoint").
    config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields",100).
    getOrCreate()

    val mySchema = StructType(Array(
     StructField("id", IntegerType),
     StructField("name", StringType),
     StructField("year", IntegerType),
     StructField("rating", DoubleType),
     StructField("duration", IntegerType)
    ))

    val xmlData = spark.readStream.option("sep", ",").schema(mySchema).csv("file:///home/sa1/kafdata/") 
    import java.util.Calendar
    val df_agg_without_time= xmlData.withColumn("event_time", to_utc_timestamp(current_timestamp, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID()))

    val df_agg_with_time = df_agg_without_time.withWatermark("event_time", "10 seconds").groupBy(window($"event_time", "10 seconds", "5 seconds"),$"year").agg(sum($"rating").as("rating"),sum($"duration").as("duration"))

   val pr = df_agg_with_time.drop("window")

    pr.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("csv").
    option("path", "hdfs://ccc/apps/hive/warehouse/rta.db/sample_movcsv/").start()
```

if i dont drop (window) column another issue will occur... that issue i have already posted here ... [How to write windowed aggregation in CSV format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54112238/how-to-write-windowed-streaming-aggregation-in-csv-format/54137507?noredirect=1#comment95107910_54137507)

can someone help on this? how to write to hdfs as csv file after aggregation..please help

Comment: Can you `ls` the hdfs location so we all can see the _"empty part files getting generated on hdfs location."_? Are there any files with data inside or are all empty?

Comment: One part file with appended .csv file is generating.. But nothing is written over there...

Comment: How often do you have any new CSV file in `file:///home/sa1/kafdata/`?

Comment: I manually trying adding... Is ther any minimum size that i need to follow during adding files

Comment: UPDATE :  i have added partitionBy on writing stream... now whenver i added new files, the old files are getting processed and available as files in hdfs location.. lets say , started streaming and file 1 added in readStream directory--nothing is showing in hdfs...file 2 added in directory..now the file 1 is reflecting in hdfs location... any idea about this delay ??

Comment: @BigD Did you get any solution of this problem?